# Let $p(n)$ the predicate $\ln{x}^{n}=n\ln{x}$. Show the implication $p(n)\Rightarrow p(n+1)$ for all natural number $n$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, logarithms

I need your help with this exercise. I don't know if what I did is correct.

Let $p(n)$ the predicate $\ln{x}^{n}=n\ln{x}$. Show the implication $p(n)\Rightarrow p(n+1)$ for all natural number $n$.

Shall I use math induction?

If $n=1$, then

$$ln{x}^{1}=1\ln{x}$$

$$ln{x}=\ln{x}$$

Therefore the statement is true for $n=1$.

If $n=k$ is true, then para $n=k+1$ is true.

Let's suppose that

$$\ln{x}^{k}=k\ln{x}$$

Then

$$\ln{x}^{k+1}=(k+1)\ln{x}$$
$$\ln({x^{k}\cdot x^{1}})=(k+1)\ln{x}$$
$$\ln{x^{k}}+\ln{x^{1}}=(k+1)\ln{x}$$
$$\ln{x^{k}}+\ln{x}=k\ln{x}+\ln{x}$$
$$k\ln{x}+\ln{x}=k\ln{x}+\ln{x}$$

Therefore, the statement is true for $n=k+1$.

Therefore, the statement is true for all natural numbers.

Comment: Saying that $\ln{\left(x^{k+1}\right)} = (k+1)\ln{(x)}$ is already a problem because that's what we want to prove. Sure, the steps after it are algebraically correct, but they're not saying anything as to what you're trying to prove. Given the nature of this proof and the motivation behind assigning the question, I think we should assume we can't use the famous power rule for logarithms.

Comment: Yes, we can not use the Problem Statement to Prove the Problem Statement. In this case, when the order of the argument is reversed, it becomes correct , @Accelerator

Comment: @Prem I used math induction. That in order for the statement be tru for all natural numbers must satisfy two conditions: 1) The statement is true for the natural number $1$. 2) If the statement is true for some natural numbers $k$, it is also true for the next natural number $k+1$. I worked the problem as my precalculus work the math induction exercises. In the 2nd condition it is assume that statement is true for some natural number $k$ and then using that hypothesis we show statements holds for $k+1$. I thought I did that. :-(

Answer (score 1):

There are two things here :

[[1]] Show that $P(n)$ is true for all $n$.
[[ this is not Explicit in the Question which is not asking to Prove this ]]

[[2]] Show that $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$.
[[ this is Explicit in the Question which is asking to Prove Exactly this ]]

We can show [[1]] in various ways, including Induction where we have to show $P(n)$ for $(n=1)$ [[ that is : we have to show $P(1)$ ]] & then show that $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$.
You have done this but in reverse :
Start with $k\ln{x}+\ln{x}=k\ln{x}+\ln{x}$
then move to $\ln{x}^{k+1}=(k+1)\ln{x}$

Here it is :

We have $n=k$ here :
$k\ln{x}=\ln{x^{k}}$ [[ Equation 1 ]]

Now, we start with :
$k\ln{x}+\ln{x}=k\ln{x}+\ln{x}$

$\ln{x^{k}}+\ln{x}=k\ln{x}+\ln{x}$ [[ using Equation 1 ]]

$\ln{x^{k}}+\ln{x^{1}}=(k+1)\ln{x}$

$\ln({x^{k}\cdot x^{1}})=(k+1)\ln{x}$

$\ln{x}^{k+1}=(k+1)\ln{x}$

We have got $n=k+1$ here :
$(k+1)\ln{x}=\ln{x^{k+1}}$ [[ Equation 2 ]]

We have shown that Equation 1 Implies Equation 2

That is DONE !

We can show [[2]] with only that Part & not worry about $P(1)$.

Comment: but $n=k$ is $\ln{x}^{k}=k\ln{x}$ not $ k\ln{x}+\ln{x}=k\ln{x}+\ln{x}$. I'm sorry I'm confused. :-(

Comment: That whole statement is not $n=k$ , it only **uses** $n=k$ to convert that LHS into the LHS on the next line. I have updated the Answer to make that more clear.

Comment: can I say this as well? After saying when $n=k: \ln{x^k}=k\ln{x}$, then if $n=k+1$: let's say that the $LHS$ is $\ln{x^{k+1}}$ and the $RHS$ is $(k+1)\ln{x}$. After, $LHS=\ln{x^{k+1}}=\ln{x^k\cdot x^1}=\ln{x^k}+\ln{x}=k\ln{x}+\ln{x}$ and $RHS=(k+1)\ln{x}=k\ln{x}+\ln{x}$. Therefore, $LHS=RHS$. Let me know if this is valid. I think is easier for me than seeing it backwards.

Comment: Yes , that is Possible , only concern is that LHS is on left & RHS is also on left !! Instead, you might want to use $A$ & $B$ to say $A=\ln...(k+1)=...$ & $B=...=(k+1)\ln...$ & hence $A=B$. Otherwise it is valid. Core 2 Points [1] Do not start with $P(k+1)$ , but start with $P(k)$ [2] Evaluate using known $n=(k)$ to get new $n=(k+1).